# Why does calloc allocate 1 byte if nelem or elsize == zero?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I am working to develop debug implementations of the four basic memory allocation routines `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, and `free` (similar in operation to Electric Fence) to debug heap corruption on embedded systems which do not have the resources to run other memory debugging tools, or for which other tools do not exist (for instance, LynxOS 7.0 for PowerPC ships with GCC 4.6.3, and a proprietary  implementation of glibc and libstdc++ which does not include the `mtrace` family of functions).

The following is the source code for calloc, from calloc.c in GCC's libiberty.

```
PTR
calloc (size_t nelem, size_t elsize)
{
  register PTR ptr;  

  if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0)
    nelem = elsize = 1;

  ptr = malloc (nelem * elsize);
  if (ptr) bzero (ptr, nelem * elsize);

  return ptr;
}
```

Why are `nelem` and `elsize` both set equal to `1` if either equals `0`?

If I attempt to allocate `0` chunks of size `n` or `n` chunks with `0` size, wouldn't either case result in an aggregate allocation of `0` total bytes, and not `1` byte?

Comment: `malloc` and `calloc` are required by specification to return unique values.

Comment: @KerrekSB But since `malloc()` already has this requirement, `calloc()` doesn't need its own check.

Comment: @Barmar I thought about your idea that "since malloc() already has this requirement, calloc() doesn't need its own check.".  A functional difference here to the redundant check is that by doing it here, the 1 byte allocation is zero'd.  Without `if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0) nelem = elsize = 1;`, the allocation remains as is.

Comment: @chux That's true, but it's undefined behavior to access the memory, so it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Barmar Agree about UB, but this is some sort of coding paradigm called _Electric Fence_ and deterministic behavior may be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just bad code, which is not unexpected from libiberty/gnulib/etc. As I understand it they already replace `malloc` if `malloc(0)` returns a null pointer rather than a unique pointer for each call, so I don't see any good reason for making `calloc` pass 1 to `malloc` instead of 0. Moreover, passing 1 breaks/undermines debugging tools like sanitizers that could tell you if you inadvertently dereferenced the pointer to a "zero-element array".

The code is also incredibly dangerous in that it does not check for overflow of the multiplication; any correct implementation of `calloc` is required to do this.

TL;DR: this code is junk.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does calloc allocate 1 byte if nelem or elsize == zero?

To reduce ambiguity.

`calloc(0, x), calloc(x, 0), malloc(0)`, when successful, may return `NULL` or a non-`NULL` pointer.  In both cases, the pointer may not be de-referenced without causing *undefined behavior* (UB).

When unsuccessful, a `NULL` pointer is returned.

By insuring the allocation size is more than 0, there is no ambiguity when `NULL` is returned - the allocation failed from *this* `calloc()`.

---

Note, a better function would also detect product overflow.

```
if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0) {
  nelem = elsize = 1;
} else if (SIZE_MAX/nelem > elsize) {
  return NULL;  // Too much for this implementation
}
...
```

---

Further thought about [Electric_Fence](https://elinux.org/Electric_Fence):

I'd expect the `malloc(0)` of that project to also insure that 0 bytes are not allocated.  Yet simply calling  `ptr = malloc (0); if (ptr) bzero (ptr, 0);` would not zero that 1 byte allocation.  `if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0) nelem = elsize = 1;` makes certain the allocation is at least 1 byte **and** that allocation is zeroed.